# Elegant way of avoiding ASP.NET MVC routing errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a route:

```
        routes.MapRoute("ResetPasswordConfirm", "reset-password-confirm", new { controller = "Membership", action = "ResetPasswordConfirm" });
```

and the code

```
    public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirm(int userid, string key)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

in my application. So that i have url to be executed like this:

```
http://localhost/reset-password-confirm?userid=1&key=bla_bla_something
```

That is absolutely okay, until someone decides to go to

```
http://localhost/reset-password-confirm
```

...and look what will happen. ASP.NET will generate predictable error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'userid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'...

It could be done also by a search robot trying to grab all the possible urls. It's okay, but generates a lot of errors during usage of application in the wild. I want to avoid that, but feel uncomfortable with writing a stub for every possible case for such kind of errors.

Is there any elegant way of doing that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to handle global errors, just set `<customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>` on your `web.config` and create an `Error.cshtml` on your `Shared` view folder. MVC3 templates actually include that page.

On the other hand, if you want to be more specific, you should try `Action Filters`, that's a cool way to handle errors.

```
[HandleError(View = "YourErrorView", ExceptionType=typeof(NullReferenceException))]
public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirm(int? userid, string key)
{
      if (!userid.HasValue)
         throw new NullReferenceException();
      // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nullables for your parameters, i.e.:

public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirm(**int?** userid, string key)

Comment: You can also use default values, though of course you are restrained by having to have them last, e.g. `public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirm(string key, int userid = 0)`